# How do I read data from a csv file, store it to memory, then write the memory back into the csv file(while removing the last line that was read)?

Tags: java, csv, bufferedreader, filereader, printwriter

My code uses a buffered reader to read a file with a list of values, and my FileWriter adds another gamer to the list. Whenever I go to run my code, the new gamer is added repeatedly. How do I read the data into memory and then write the memory back into the file without the last line added?

Input:

```java
package week3assignment;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Jaret_Dalrymple_GamesReport {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File gameScores = new File("C:\\Users\\jaret\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\GameScores.csv");
        readWrite(gameScores);
        addGamer(gameScores, "Jimmy", "189", "190", "197", "199", "198", "193", "199", "199", "188", "196");
        readWrite2(gameScores);
    }

    private static void readWrite(File gameScores) throws IOException {

        if (gameScores.exists()) {
            BufferedReader br = null;
            String line = "";
            String csvSplitBy = ",";
            int gamerCount = 0;
            int topScore = 0;
            String topScorer = "";
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(gameScores));
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Games Report");
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Gamer   1   2   3   4   5   6   7");
            System.out.println("    8   9   10  Total");
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("-------------------------------------");

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String list[] = new String[10];
                list = line.split(csvSplitBy);
                int sum = 0;

                for (String element : list) {
                    try {
                        Integer num = Integer.parseInt(element);
                        sum += num;
                    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                        System.out.print(list[0] + "\t" + list[1] + (list[1].length() > 10 ? "\t" : "\t") + list[2]
                                + (list[2].length() > 10 ? "\t" : "\t") + list[3]
                                + (list[3].length() > 10 ? "\t" : "\t") + list[4]
                                + (list[4].length() > 10 ? "\t" : "\t") + list[5]
                                + (list[5].length() > 10 ? "\t" : "\t") + list[6]
                                + (list[6].length() > 10 ? "\t" : "\t") + list[7]
                                + (list[7].length() > 10 ? "\n\t" : "\n\t") + list[8]
                                + (list[8].length() > 10 ? "\t" : "\t") + list[9]
                                + (list[9].length() > 10 ? "\t" : "\t") + list[10] + "\t");
                    }
                }
                if (sum > topScore) {
                    topScore = sum;
                    topScorer = list[0];
                }

                System.out.println(sum);
                gamerCount++;
            }

            System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("# of Gamers:    " + gamerCount);
            System.out.println("Top Gamer:  " + topScorer);
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
            br.close();
        }
    }

    private static void addGamer(File gameScores, String first, String second, String third, String fourth,
            String fifth, String sixth, String seventh, String eighth, String ninth, String tenth, String eleventh)
            throws IOException {
        FileWriter newGamer = new FileWriter(gameScores, true);
        newGamer.write("\n" + first + "," + second + "," + third + "," + fourth + "," + fifth + "," + sixth + "," + 
        seventh + "," + eighth + "," + ninth + "," + tenth + "," + eleventh);
        newGamer.close();
        System.out.println("Gamer Jimmy record added.");;
    }

    private static void readWrite2(File gameScores) throws IOException {

        if (gameScores.exists()) {
            BufferedReader br = null;
            String line = "";
            String csvSplitBy = ",";
            int gamerCount = 0;
            int topScore = 0;
            String topScorer = "";
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(gameScores, true);
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(gameScores));
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Games Report");
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Gamer   1   2   3   4   5   6   7");
            System.out.println("    8   9   10  Total");
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("-------------------------------------");

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String list[] = new String[10];
                list = line.split(csvSplitBy);
                int sum = 0;

                for (String element : list) {
                    try {
                        Integer num = Integer.parseInt(element);
                        sum += num;
                    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                        System.out.print(list[0] + "\t" + list[1] + (list[1].length() > 10 ? "\t" : "\t") + list[2]
                                + (list[2].length() > 10 ? "\t" : "\t") + list[3]
                                + (list[3].length() > 10 ? "\t" : "\t") + list[4]
                                + (list[4].length() > 10 ? "\t" : "\t") + list[5]
                                + (list[5].length() > 10 ? "\t" : "\t") + list[6]
                                + (list[6].length() > 10 ? "\t" : "\t") + list[7]
                                + (list[7].length() > 10 ? "\n\t" : "\n\t") + list[8]
                                + (list[8].length() > 10 ? "\t" : "\t") + list[9]
                                + (list[9].length() > 10 ? "\t" : "\t") + list[10] + "\t");
                    }
                }
                if (sum > topScore) {
                    topScore = sum;
                    topScorer = list[0];
                }

                System.out.println(sum);
                gamerCount++;
            }

            System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("# of Gamers:    " + gamerCount);
            System.out.println("Top Gamer:  " + topScorer);
            
            br.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Ouput:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------
Games Report
----------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------
Gamer   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
    8   9   10  Total
----------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------
Bob 167 123 159 102 102 189 183
    173 197 148 1543
Sally   189 130 138 113 159 116 134
    196 150 144 1469
Mario   104 106 120 188 143 189 149
    174 163 100 1436
Lev 152 159 195 140 154 176 107
    128 166 181 1558
Carden  158 200 175 114 117 150 176
    181 131 132 1534
Adelie  175 199 122 104 198 182 175
    153 120 165 1593
Lada    161 108 102 193 151 197 115
    137 126 186 1476
Xavier  178 171 147 113 107 129 128
    189 165 195 1522
Raffi   176 144 151 124 149 112 158
    159 119 177 1469
Chang   135 144 177 153 143 125 145
    140 117 158 1437
Mich    156 105 178 137 165 180 128
    115 139 157 1460
Mason   162 185 108 106 113 135 139
    135 197 160 1440
Cora    186 115 106 126 135 108 157
    156 187 120 1396
Sergio  117 105 115 116 193 200 176
    134 122 153 1431
Jonas   132 163 196 101 134 159 131
    104 135 168 1423
Jimmy   189 190 197 199 198 193 199
    199 188 196 1948
----------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------
# of Gamers:    16
Top Gamer:  Jimmy
----------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------
Gamer Jimmy record added.
----------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------
Games Report
----------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------
Gamer   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
    8   9   10  Total
----------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------
Bob 167 123 159 102 102 189 183
    173 197 148 1543
Sally   189 130 138 113 159 116 134
    196 150 144 1469
Mario   104 106 120 188 143 189 149
    174 163 100 1436
Lev 152 159 195 140 154 176 107
    128 166 181 1558
Carden  158 200 175 114 117 150 176
    181 131 132 1534
Adelie  175 199 122 104 198 182 175
    153 120 165 1593
Lada    161 108 102 193 151 197 115
    137 126 186 1476
Xavier  178 171 147 113 107 129 128
    189 165 195 1522
Raffi   176 144 151 124 149 112 158
    159 119 177 1469
Chang   135 144 177 153 143 125 145
    140 117 158 1437
Mich    156 105 178 137 165 180 128
    115 139 157 1460
Mason   162 185 108 106 113 135 139
    135 197 160 1440
Cora    186 115 106 126 135 108 157
    156 187 120 1396
Sergio  117 105 115 116 193 200 176
    134 122 153 1431
Jonas   132 163 196 101 134 159 131
    104 135 168 1423
Jimmy   189 190 197 199 198 193 199
    199 188 196 1948
Jimmy   189 190 197 199 198 193 199
    199 188 196 1948
----------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------
# of Gamers:    17
Top Gamer:  Jimmy
```

Comment: Why do you want to add something to the file just to delete it afterward?

Comment: So I can rerun the code. If I run it repeatedly, then the new gamer gets added every iteration. @JoãoDias

Comment: You can't open the file in append mode. This will not remove any data from the file. 1) You need to read the data into your ArrayList and close the file. 2) Delete the last item in the ArrayList.  3) Then open the file for output and then write the data from the ArrayList to the file.

Comment: How would I go about deleting the last item in the Arraylist? @camickr

Comment: If you are introduced to a new class then take the time to read the API first. This way you get an idea of all the functionality the class provides. That is how you learn about different classes in the JDK. There is a method that gives you the number of items in the ArrayList and a method to remove a specific item.

Comment: I'm doing some reading and I'm seeing that the File class does not have a close() method. Also in my code I am using an array rather than an ArrayList. @camickr

Comment: You already have the `close()` method. This is not new. The point is you can't delete data from a file. You need to completely recreate the file. So you need to read all the data into memory and then write the memory back to the file (except for the last line). I suggested using an ArrayList as your "memory" since you don't need to know how many lines are in the file. You are using an Array to process the data in each line. That does not change.

Comment: Sure, but what is the purpose of it? Why adding it and then delete it? What is the actual use case that you are trying to tackle? that is my actual question.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a while loop with this condition:
`line = br.readLine() != null`
You could change it to something like this:

```
line = br.readLine();
while(line != null){
   your code here...
} // end loop
```

You could make a temporary variable to store the line you're using on the loop, and in case the code exits finally the loop, get that line and delete it from the csv.

PS: Sorry if I didn't explain myself as good as I would like, just starting on this.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

A most basic example of writing data from an ArrayList:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    lines.add("one");
    lines.add("two");
    lines.add("three");

    File file = new File("testing.txt");
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter( file ) );

    for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
    {
        if (i > 0)
            writer.newLine();

        writer.write( lines.get(i) );
    }

    writer.close();
}
```

So you first need to read your data into the ArrayList and delete the last item before writing out the data in the ArrayList.